# How do I make sure numbers I import from my server will import to the right location?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, expo, position

My current RN app imports numeric values from my server. When these values are imported however, the values either don’t show up, or show up on top of each other, instead of side by side. Why might this happen and how can I make sure this stops happening?

Below is my code for the current iteration:

```
const displayNumber1 = async () =>{ 

  let response = await server_instance.get_information
        
    getNumeric1( 

     <Text style = {styles.one}> {response.number} </Text> ) 
}
```

`

```
const displayNumber2 = async () =>{ 
    
    let response = await server_instance.get_information2
        
        getNumeric2( 
    
    <Text style = {styles.two}> {response.number2} </Text> 
) 
    
}

displayNumber1()
displayNumber2()
```

...

```
return(

 <View style = {{flexDirection: 'row'}}>      

    <View style = {styles.blank}>    

  <Text style = {{textAlign: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: height*0.016, marginLeft: width*0.04*/}}>{i18n.t('numeric1')}</Text>  

  <Text style = {{textAlign: 'center', paddingTop: height*0.015, fontSize: height*0.027, color: '#009387' }}>{Numeric1}</Text>     

</View>

<View style = {styles.blank}>
  <View style = {[ styles.offer, {marginLeft: 10}]}>
    <Text style = {{textAlign: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: height*0.016}}>{i18n.t('numeric2')}</Text>
    <Text style = {{textAlign: 'center', paddingTop: height*0.015, fontSize: height*0.027, color: '#009387' }}>{numeric2}</Text> 
  </View>
</View>
```